Understanding negative partial dependency values
What does a negative partial dependency value (centered/mean value), such as a change from -0.8 to -0.7 with an increase in input, indicate for a parameter?
Does this mean the parameter has a negative relationship with the output, or does it imply that the predictions are generally lower than average?


Just some initial context:
Partial dependence plots show the average relationship between a given feature $x_A$ and the response $y$ within the fixed, joint distribution of all the other inputs $x_B, \dots, x_Z$.
That said, when displaying the actual plot, we might choose to display the changes relative to an overall central tendency (e.g. the median) or just display the raw values. In the plot shown, this is not defined, so I will answer for both cases:

If we are showing the centred values: The partial dependency values being consistently negative is a strong indication that the feature value tends to pull the model's predictions below the average across a wide range of the feature's values. Something like "number of cigarettes smoked (our $x_A$) and overall lung health" (our $y$), at no point smoking cigarettes improves lung health on average so all other things being equal, the PDP values for number of cigarettes smoked will always be negative. (i.e. below our central tendency)
If we are showing the raw values of the PDPs: We predict negative values on average across all values of feature $x_A$, that is not a problem, our dataset may be like that after all. (e.g. predicting temperature in Antarctica)

Small caveat: Univariate PDPs are good for small fast investigations but do consider looking at some interactions of our $x_A$ feature with other features. Especially on larger ML models (e.g. GBMs with hundreds of base learners) we might have strong heterogenous interaction effects.

my problem is a regression problem. In another place, such as this Kaggle notebook (https://www.kaggle.com/code/alfazick/partial-dependence-plots), I noticed that they plot the average predicted price on the vertical axis. You will see some negative numbers. They mentioned that "that doesn’t mean the price would sell for a negative amount. Instead, it means the predicted prices would have been less than the actual average price for that distance."

I mean that a negative value on the y-axis does not necessarily indicate a negative correlation. Can we say if the curve shows an increasing trend as input values increase, it suggests a positive relationship between the input and output, regardless of whether the output values are negative?

They are correct, but note that their y-scales plot are centred at 0. These are centred values around the average price. That's why they say that "the predicted prices would have been less than the actual average price for that distance".  And yes, the slope of the PDP is informative in the way you described, a positive slope suggests that increases in the input get translated even if they remain below average (and thus appear negative).

sorry i cannot understand "get translated".  I mean can we say if the curve shows an increasing trend in y-axis (PDP values are negative, like here from -0.8 to -0.7) as input values increase (from -1 to +1), it suggests a positive relationship between the input and output, regardless of whether the output values are negative?

Sorry, I answered it quickly "(...) increases in the input get translated in increases in the response variable even if (...)". Yes, that is correct.
